# Definition required: mixed-level simulation

Tags: simulation

Could someone please describe/define what 'mixed-level simulation' is? It keeps coming up in the literature I'm going through.

Thanks.

P

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the manual of ngspice and came across the following sentence:

> Historically, circuit simulators have supported either an analog simulation algorithm or a digital simulation algorithm. Ngspice inherits the XSPICE framework and supports both analog and digital algorithms and is a "mixed-mode" simulator.

Therefore, this implies that 'mixed-level' simulations take into account both analog and digital signals. Again, from the ngspice manual (Section 1.1.3):

> Modern circuits often contain a mix of analog and digital circuits. To simulate such circuits efficiently and accurately a mix of analog and digital simulation techniques is required. When analog simulation algorithms are combined with digital simulation algorithms, the result is termed “mixed-mode simulation”.

Comment: That's mixed-mode, not mixed-level. I suspect mixed-level refers to different levels of abstraction, such as using ideal opamp models in non critical areas, but transistor models in the low noise front end.